# Datagridview with a checkbox default set to true

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a datagridview with a checkbox default set to true on the code:

```
Protected Sub dgvStudent_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvStudent.DataBound

    Dim chkstudentid As CheckBox = CType(dgvStudent.Rows(10).Cells(1).FindControl("chkRequired"), CheckBox)

    chkstudentid.Checked = True
```

This works fine, however, when I unchecked the checkbox and click on the submit button and reload the page it again checked the student checkbox.
Do I have to add another piece of code so that when the checkbox is not checked it is saved successfully?

Comment: Of course everytime you reload the grid (set its datasource) the DataBound event is triggered so the check is again set to true. Perhaps you should use a different event or a different place in your code. For example when you first call the load of the grid change the initial set then do not touch it again unless you have a specific requirement to reset it to true

Comment: the checkbox should be checked by default. Now i need to unchecked and save it. Should some code be written on the save event button? am not sure

Comment: What's the data binding setup on the dgvStudent?  Is there a data table object with a Boolean field for that column?  Generally in my experience you are far better doing data manipulations at that level rather than direct in the UI as you are here.  Leave the UI for what it does best which is User Interaction